# UIImage *rightIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.jpg"];

Tags: iphone

```
UIImage *rightIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.jpg"];
UIBarButtonItem *btnFB = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:rightIcon 
                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                         target:self 
                                                         action:@selector(FBConnect)];
[_barItems insertObject:btnFB atIndex:0];
```

I have written this code but I am not able to display images in a `TabBar`.

Comment: What is this,...what you want to ask?

Comment: add tab bar button with image but image is not display.

Comment: you must use `.png` files, the `.jpg` is not supported resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self getfbBtn];

- (UIBarButtonItem *) getfbBtn
{
    UIButton * backBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,22.0f,22.0f)];
    [backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(FBConnect) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
    return backBarButton;    
}

//Action For RightBarButton - FBBtn
- (void)FBConnect
{
    NSLog(@"fb connect btn press");
}
```